# How to capture delivery date when using UPS Rate API in php?

Tags: php, fedex, ups

I'm using this endpoint to request for estimated rate
https://wwwcie.ups.com/webservices/Rate

I noticed that the XML response doesn't contain any delivery date. I do see BusinessDaysInTransit though. However, I'm not sure if it's our responsible to do the manual coding of figuring out what the delivery date is. I couldn't find anything in their api documentation.

Comment: I was able to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the **Time In Transit** API instead. The Rate API does not provide the estimated delivery date.

[image]

Comment: Rate API will support the return of time in transit information when new RequestOptions “shoptimeintransit” and “ratetimeintransit” are passed, along with the new DeliveryTimeInformation container. For example, <Request> <TransactionReference> <XpciVersion>1.0</XpciVersion> </TransactionReference> <RequestAction>Rate</RequestAction> <RequestOption>Shoptimeintransit</RequestOption> </Request>

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but to get this in the rate call you need to change the RequestOption to "RateTimeInTransit" add the DeliveryTimeInformation container to the request:

```
    {
       "UPSSecurity":{
          "UsernameToken":{
             "Username":"removed",
             "Password":"removed"
          },
          "ServiceAccessToken":{
             "AccessLicenseNumber":"removed"
          }
       },
       "RateRequest":{
          "Request":{
             "RequestOption":"RateTimeInTransit",
             "TransactionReference":{
                "CustomerContext":"ORDER123"
             }
          },
          "Shipment":{
             "Shipper":{
                "Name":"ShipperName",
                "ShipperNumber":"removed",
                "Address":{
                   "AddressLine":[
                      "123 Sesame St"
                   ],
                   "City":"Nibley",
                   "StateProvinceCode":"UT",
                   "PostalCode":"84321",
                   "CountryCode":"US"
                }
             },
             "ShipTo":{
                "Name":null,
                "AttentionName":"Ship to Name",
                "Address":{
                   "AddressLine":[
                      "123 RealAddress ST"
                   ],
                   "City":"Hyrum",
                   "StateProvinceCode":"UT",
                   "PostalCode":"84319",
                   "CountryCode":"US",
                   "ResidentialAddressIndicator":"Y"
                }
             },
             "ShipFrom":{
                "Name":"Ima Shipper",
                "Address":{
                   "AddressLine":[
                      "123 Sesame St"
                   ],
                   "City":"Nibley",
                   "StateProvinceCode":"UT",
                   "PostalCode":"84321",
                   "CountryCode":"US"
                }
             },
             "Service":{
                "Code":"03"
             },
             "Package":{
                "PackagingType":{
                   "Code":"02"
                },
                "Dimensions":{
                   "UnitOfMeasurement":{
                      "Code":"IN",
                      "Description":"inches"
                   },
                   "Length":"5",
                   "Width":"4",
                   "Height":"3"
                },
                "PackageWeight":{
                   "UnitOfMeasurement":{
                      "Code":"Lbs",
                      "Description":"pounds"
                   },
                   "Weight":"1"
                }
             },
             "ShipmentRatingOptions":{
                "NegotiatedRatesIndicator":"Y",
                "RateChartIndicator":"Y"
             },
             "DeliveryTimeInformation":{
                "PackageBillType": "03",
                "Pickup":{
                    "Date":"20191224"
                }
          }
       }
    }
```

If using the UPS JSON Developer Guide you will need to combine info from WebServices guide to know which containers you are missing since the JSON documentation is poor.